# How to create an Admin shortcut with NSIS?

Tags: batch-file, nsis, shortcut-file

I have an NSIS script that works great, and creates Start menu shortcuts, one of which points to a batch file.  The issue is the user will have to right-click and Run as Administrator or it will fail.  Is there a way to create the shortcut to Run as Administrator?  I am not trying to bypass security, just have it prompt the UAC automatically.  The only alternative I could think of is to instruct the user in the batch file, which is tacky IMO.  I also thought of searching for Run as Administrator for the batch file itself, but also came up empty.

Here is the Start Menu section of my NSIS installer:

```
# CREATE SHORTCUTS

!insertmacro MUI_STARTMENU_WRITE_BEGIN MySoftware
    # Create shortcut.
    SetShellVarContext all
    CreateDirectory "$SMPROGRAMS\$SMGroup"
    CreateDirectory "$SMPROGRAMS\$SMGroup\Uninstaller"
    SetOutPath $SMPROGRAMS\$SMGroup
    CreateShortCut "$SMPROGRAMS\$SMGroup\GO.lnk" "$INSTDIR\bin\go.bat"
    CreateShortcut "$SMPROGRAMS\$SMGroup\Uninstaller\Uninstall.lnk" $INSTDIR\Uninstaller.exe

    SectionGetFlags ${SEC_SCHEDULER} $R0 
    IntOp $R0 $R0 & ${SF_SELECTED} 
    IntCmp $R0 ${SF_SELECTED} svc jump1 jump1 
    svc:
    # Create shortcut to Scheduler Service Manager    
    CreateShortCut "$SMPROGRAMS\$SMGroup\Scheduler.lnk" "$INSTDIR\bin\${SVC_MGR_BAT}"
    jump1:
    DetailPrint "Registry Entry: ${REGKEY}\StartMenu : $SMGroup"
    WriteRegStr HKLM "${REGKEY}" StartMenu $SMGroup
!insertmacro MUI_STARTMENU_WRITE_END
```

Edit: I have checked the CreateShortCut reference, and see no mention of it, but thought there might be some workaround elsewhere in the NSIS script.
[CreateShortCut NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#4.9.3.4)

Answer (score 3):

There is a feature request for this [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/nsis/feature-requests/513/) but it has various issues so it has not been implemented:

- Pre-Vista will show the NT5 RunAs user dialog and you can authenticate with any user there, does not have to be an administrator.
- What happens when UAC is off?
- Users could run your batch file manually or create their own shortcuts.

If you still believe this is a good idea you can use [this](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/IShellLink_Set_RunAs_flag) or [this](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/ShellLink_plug-in)...